# Regex split string and check if string is of type

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Aanval op Vlemis (499|453) C44

This is what the string looks like. Though it's actually like this: "Aanval op variable (variable) variable

What I want to do is 1: get the coordinates (I already have this), 2 get Vlemis (first variable), get C44 (third variable) and check to see if the string is of this type.

My code:

```
  $("#commands_table tr.nowrap").each(function(){
            var text = $(this).find("input[id*='editInput']").val();



                            var attackername= text.match(/(?=op)[\s|\w]*(?=\()/);
                            var coordinates = text.match(/\(\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}\)/);



                            });
```

Coordinates works, attackername however doesn't.

Html:

```
  <span id="labelText[6]">Aanval op Vlemis (499|453) C44</span>
```

Comment: What are the coordinates, what is the attackername? Which of the variables are you talking about.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but could you not grab the contents of the span, split it at the spaces and reference accordingly?

Comment: Yes I could, but that would only work for this type of string. I can only check if the string matches a type with Regex :) Coodinates = (xxx|yyy), attackername = first variable (vlemis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one regex to take everything :

```
var parts = text.match(/(\w+)\s*\((\d+)\|(\d+)\)\s*(\w+)/).slice(1);
```

This builds

```
["Vlemis", "499", "453", "C44"]
```

If you're not sure the string is valid, test like this :

```
var parts = text.match(/(\w+)\s*\((\d+)\|(\d+)\)\s*(\w+)/);
if (parts) {
    parts = parts.slice(1);
    // do things with parts
} else {
    // no match, yell at the user
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! The script stops running when a string doesn't match though (for example, some strings are like this: 549|567 (Vlemis) Ver=100, Kata=3), how could I check if a string is of the type I mentioned, then run the regex when it does match? Or am I doing something wrong. (I'm using alert to test it btw)

if (parts != null && parts.length > 0)  maybe?

Comment: Thanks alot for the fast answer!